# How To Represent 0.1 In Floating Point Arithmetic And Decimal

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, decimal, bit-representation

I am trying to understand floating point arithmetic better and have seen a few links to 'What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic'.

I still don't understand how a number like `0.1` or `0.5` is stored in floats and as decimals.

Can someone please explain how it is laid out is memory?

I know about the float being two parts (i.e., a number to the power of something).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've always pointed people towards [Harald Schmidt's online converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), along with the [Wikipedia IEEE754-1985 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) with its nice pictures.

For those two specific values, you get (for 0.1):

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm    1/n
0 01111011 10011001100110011001101
           |  ||  ||  ||  ||  || +- 8388608
           |  ||  ||  ||  ||  |+--- 2097152
           |  ||  ||  ||  ||  +---- 1048576
           |  ||  ||  ||  |+-------  131072
           |  ||  ||  ||  +--------   65536
           |  ||  ||  |+-----------    8192
           |  ||  ||  +------------    4096
           |  ||  |+---------------     512
           |  ||  +----------------     256
           |  |+-------------------      32
           |  +--------------------      16
           +-----------------------       2
```

The sign is positive, that's pretty easy.

The exponent is `64+32+16+8+2+1 = 123 - 127 bias = -4`, so the multiplier is `2-4` or `1/16`.

The mantissa is chunky. It consists of `1` (the implicit base) plus (for all those bits with each being worth `1/(2n)` as `n` starts at `1` and increases to the right), `{1/2, 1/16, 1/32, 1/256, 1/512, 1/4096, 1/8192, 1/65536, 1/131072, 1/1048576, 1/2097152, 1/8388608}`.

When you add all these up, you get `1.60000002384185791015625`.

When you multiply that by the multiplier, you get `0.100000001490116119384765625`, which is why they say you cannot represent `0.1` exactly as an IEEE754 float, and provides so much opportunity on SO for people answering `"why doesn't 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3?"`-type questions :-)

---

The 0.5 example is substantially easier. It's represented as:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 01111110 00000000000000000000000
```

which means it's the implicit base, `1`, plus no other additives (all the mantissa bits are zero).

The sign is again positive. The exponent is `64+32+16+8+4+2 = 126 - 127 bias = -1`. Hence the multiplier is `2-1` which is `1/2` or `0.5`.

So the final value is `1` multiplied by `0.5`, or `0.5`. Voila!

---

I've sometimes found it easier to think of it in terms of decimal.

The number 1.345 is equivalent to

```
1 + 3/10   + 4/100 + 5/1000
```

or:

```
        -1       -2      -3
1 + 3*10   + 4*10  + 5*10
```

---

Similarly, the IEEE754 representation for decimal `0.8125` is:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 01111110 10100000000000000000000
```

With the implicit base of 1, that's equivalent to the binary:

```
         01111110-01111111
1.101 * 2
```

or:

```
                     -1
(1   + 1/2 + 1/8) * 2     (no 1/4 since that bit is 0)
```

which becomes:

```
(8/8 + 4/8 + 1/8) * 1/2
```

and *then* becomes:

```
13/8 * 1/2 = 0.8125
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) and [the IEEE group](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/), first.

Basically, there's a sign, a number, and an exponent. A number in one base cannot be represented finitely in another base if the source base has factors not present in the destination base. For instance, 1/3 cannot be represented as a finite decimal number, but is trivial to represent as a ternary (base-3) number: (0.1)<sub>3</sub>.

So 0.5 has a *finite* binary representation, (0.1)<sub>2</sub>, that is, 2<sup>-1</sup>, but 0.1 has a *repeating* representation because 2 and 10 have a factor (5) not in common.