# IEEE Double Precision

Tags: standards, ieee-754

Standard IEEEDoublePrecision
What is the largest and smallest number be displayed in the standard? how is it?

Comment: Smells like homework. And an answer that can be found on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The largest "number" you can store in IEEE754 double precision is `Infinity`, the smallest is `-Infinity`.

If you mean non-infinite representations, then that would be roughly

`±1.7976931348623157 x 10`<sup><sup>`308`</sup></sup>.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855) for an excellent answer regarding IEEE754 formats. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for a wikipedia article showing the representation.

Comment: Hence the quotes around `"number"`.