# How to convert a number to the IEEE 745 single-precision floating point representation?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

How can I convert the number  123.45678 * 10^-22 
to the IEEE 745 single-precision floating point representation? Can you show me the steps?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want binary scientific notation. That is, you want your number to be of the form 2<sup>α</sup>, and you need to split α into its integral and its fractional part, α = *k* + β, with β < 1 and *k* ∈ ℤ.

To find α, take logarithms: α = log<sub>2</sub>123.45678 − 22 log<sub>2</sub>10.

The integral part of the exponent, *k*, is stored in the exponent field of the IEEE float (after adjusting by the bias), and the fractional part 2<sup>β</sup> is stored in the mantissa (omitting the leading 1).