# Fastest C++ Rational Number library

Tags: c++, performance, gmp, rational-numbers

I'm using [GMPXX](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Rationals.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Rationals) wrapper of [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) and it is not fast enough. Is it possible to find some comparison of rational number libraries' speed?

During my calculation a very big rational number will appear with 10^100 denominator and same size numerator.

Do you know something faster than GMP?

Answer (score 5):

> Do you know something faster than GMP?

It appears the Haskell folks faced a similar problem as yours. Here are their notes:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReplacingGMPNotes
- http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReplacingGMPNotes/PerformanceMeasurements

Comment: at this point, if you can consider a switch to another language consider Python.

Comment: @axis, Python has a built-in Rational class but there's no reason to believe it will be speedier than C++.

Answer (score -5):

A rational is a float/double, the problem with that is basically the base 2 ( used by computers ) vs base 10 ( used by humans in the classic math calculus ), in the end getting a good **representation** of a generic rational number is a good challenge, considering a value with a magnitude of 10^100 this becomes an extremely good challenge.

I think that you should pause for a minute and think about this because a float generated by 10^100/10^100 can be really gigantic and doing this with a computer is something for a really advanced lab in my opinion, you can't expect a library to solve this kind of problems with efficiency and most importantly with accuracy with a magnitude this big.

[further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855)

Comment: I fear that you have missed the OP's point. He isn't using `float` or `double`. In fact, he isn't using floating-point representation at all. He is using a library called GMP which can store arbitrarily large numbers (beyond 32-bit or 64-bit). Yes, doing the math in software instead of in hardware **is** slower, and he is asking who publishes the fastest such software.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm supposed to suggest assembly or a random optimized assembly instruction set ? For what i know the problem base 2 vs base 10 still remains; store a number that i large or small but this problem is still there.

Comment: @axis, rational numbers are represented as two integers, a numerator and a denominator. If the denominator is a power of 10 then you can precisely represent any decimal number you want. The base2/base10 problem doesn't occur with integers.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok, and what are you doing with this numbers ? just using random portion of memory for sport ? If you are going to use a rational it will be a float or worst.