# The numeric value of a IEEE floating point representation

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee

I am studying for an exam and I am confused about finding the "V" (The numeric value represented) and "f" fraction, in floating point rep

Let us use this example
16 bit:

`|S (1 bit)|exp( 7 bit)|M (8 bit)|`

Find:
exp: the value represented by considering the exponent field to be an unsigned integer
`E`: the value of the exponent after biasing
`M`: the value of the significant
`V`: the numeric value represented
`f`: the value of the fraction

Start with: 10.0000001

1. Find our Bias: 2^(k-1)-1, Bias = 2(^6)-1 = 63
2. Shift decimal: 1.00000001, E = 1 from a 2^1 shift
3. M is to the right of the decimal, M = 00000001
4. Find exp = E = exp - Bias, exp = 64
5. sign bit is 0 when looking to the bit right after the decimal

Is this correct so far?

So our fp rep is : `0100000000000001 Hex: 0x4001`

Now my question what is f and V?

I understand V is found from `-1^s*M*2^E` but I seem to have something messed up.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*V* is the value you started with, 10.0000001<sub>2</sub>. Either the formula for *V* is incorrect (it should have *f* in place of *M*, so *V* = (-1)<sup>2</sup>·*f*·2<sup>*E*</sup>) or the definition of *M* is incorrect (it should be the entire fraction, not the portion with the initial 1 removed).

*f* is the fraction portion of the representation. For normal values, *f* = 1+*M*. (For subnormal values, *f* = 0+*M*.) So, in this example, *f* is 1.00000001<sub>2</sub>.

Additionally, the sign bit is not taken from the bit to the right of the radix point. The sign bit is 0 if the number is positive and 1 if the number is negative.