# Infinite "for" loop when using not equal

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point

Hi this is surely simple but i cant find the answer to why this doesn't quit the loop after 0.9

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            float x;
            for(x=.1;x!=1.0;x+=.1)
            printf("%f\n", x);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: did you try a while loop? Or try x < 1.0 and see what happens.

Comment: A simple search on SO for "floating point equality" probably returns hundreds of results. Also, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577689/why-double-plus-sometimes-right-sometimes-wrong?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791764/c-c-1-00000-1-0f-false there are hundreds of duplicates here, do a search first

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3):

For your code to work, this

```
float x;
for(x=.1;x!=1.0;x+=.1)
  printf("%f\n", x);
return 0;
```

Needs to be something like

```
float x;
for(x=.1;x < 1.0;x+=.1)
  printf("%f\n", x);
return 0;
```

The explanation is the representation of floating point numbers in [IEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), in base 2 `1/5` is a recurring fraction - and that isn't precisely representable so it's rounded.

Answer (score 0):

When a computer tries to represent 0.1 as a floating point, it uses base 2. However, this does not allow an *exact* representation of 0.1, only an approximate one. When the 10th iteration is reached, you have something very close to 1.0, but not exactly. This causes the `!=` to evaluate to true, and the loop keeps going. Change it from `!=` to `<`, and it will run correctly. See the link in Elliott Frisch's answer for more information.

Comment: Why the -1?  This answer is simple, concise, truthful, and it speaks directly to the question.  The only thing is leaves out is that 1.0 _does_ have an exact representation in base 2, and so ten _inexact_ 0.1's do not add up to one exact 1.0.