# iOS - rounding a float with roundf() is not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, calc

I am having issue with rounding a float in iPhone application.

```
float f=4.845;
float s= roundf(f * 100.0)/100;
    NSLog(@"Output-1: %.2f",s);
      s= roundf(484.5)/100;
    NSLog(@"Output-2: %.2f",s);

Output-1: 4.84
Output-2: 4.85
```

Let me know whats problem in this and how to solve this.

Comment: what output r u expecting?

Comment: what are you trying to do?? you are using float, not real number

Comment: Do `NSLog(@"%f", 4.845f * 100);` and `NSLog(@"%f", 484.5f);` to see that they are not equal

Comment: I have solved it with work around solution  NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(f*100)]; float s=roundf([str floatValue]);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you don't yet realise one of the inherent problems with floating point: the fact that most numbers cannot be represented exactly <sup>(a)</sup>.

This means that `4.845` is likely to be, in reality, something like `4.8449999999999` which, when you round it, gives you `4.84` rather than what you expect, `4.85`.

And what value you end up with also depends on *how* you calculate it, which is why you're getting a different result.

And, of course, no floating point "inaccuracy" answer would be complete on SO without the authoritative [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Only sums of exact powers of two, within a certain similar range, can be exactly rendered in IEEE754. So, for example, `484.5` is

`256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 4 + 0.5` (`28 + 27 + 26 + 25 + 22 +  2-1`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855) for a more detailed look into the IEEE754 format.

---

As to solving it, you have a few choices. One is to use `double` instead of `float`. That gives you more precision and greater range of numbers but only moves the problem further away rather than really solving it. Since `0.1` is a repeating fraction in IEEE754, *no* amount of bits (short of infinity) can exactly represent it.

Another choice is to use a custom library like a big decimal type, which can represent decimals of arbitrary precision (that's *not* infinite precision as some people are wont to suggest, since it's limited by memory). This will reduce the errors caused by the binary/decimal mismatch.

You may also want to look into `NSDecimalNumber` - this doesn't give you arbitrary precision but it does give a large range with accurate decimal representation.

There'll still be numbers you can't represent, like PI or the square root of 2 or any other irrational number, but it should cover most cases. If you *really* need to handle those other values, you need to switch to symbolic numeric representations.

Comment: In Objective-C, you can use `NSDecimalNumber` to avoid this kind of problem. It is not a "big decimal type", but represents decimal numbers with up to 38 digits exactly.

Comment: Yes we can solved it with NSDecimalNumber but I have solved it with work around solution NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(f*100)]; float s=roundf([str floatValue]);

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `484.5` which can be represented exactly as a float<sup>*</sup> , `4.845` is represented as `4.8449998` (see [this calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) if you wish to try other numbers). Multiplying by one hundred keeps the number at `484.49998`, which correctly rounds to `484`.

---

<sup>*</sup> An exact representation is possible because its fractional part `0.5` is a power of two (i.e. `2^-1`).