# Clarification of definitions in IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I'm having trouble understanding what certain terms mean within IEEE Std 754-2008 (the standard for floating-point arithmetic). A few of their definitions seem somewhat circular, and so I'm just after some clarification.

In section 2.1, some basic definitions are listed. The ones I'm interested in are:

*2.1.26 floating-point representation: An unencoded member of a floating-point format, representing a finite number, a signed infinity, a quiet NaN, or a signaling Nan. A representation of a finite number has three components: a sign, an exponent, and a significand; its numerical value is the signed product of its significand and its radix raised to the power of its exponent.*

*2.1.27 format: A set of representations of numerical values and symbols, perhaps accompanied by an encoding.*

Then in section 3.1, we have the following:

*Formats are characterized by their radix, precision, and exponent range, and each format can represent a unique set of floating-point data (see 3.3).*

I'm confused as to what is meant by "a floating-point format". Is it just the set of floating-point representations with a given precision, and given bound on the exponent of the base?

That is, am I right in thinking that a floating point format is the set containing the two signed infinities, the two NaNs, and all numbers of the form (-1)^sign x b^exponent x significand, where sign is 0 or 1, exponent is some integer between two given constants, emin, and emax, and significand is a number greater than 0 and strictly less than 10, with up to p siginificant digits (where p is fixed)? Furthermore, am I right in thinking that a floating-point representation is just "some member" of the above set?

Comment: FWIW, refer to these links: [One](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) and [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3448855/6059114)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Represent 0.1 In Floating Point Arithmetic And Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - I know what floating-point numbers are. I understand why 0.1 can't be represented in floating-point arithmetic in radix 2. I'm seeking specific clarification on the terms "floating-point format" and "floating-point representation". This is more of a question of semantics, rather than a question about floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your knowledge seems pretty correct about the terminology for the 5 commonly used formats.  Each of these floating-point formats follow the same scheme and differ only in exponent size, exponent offset, and radix size.  A number has a floating-point representation where the representation is however many bits that follow the format to describe the number.

However, as the Enron scandal, Madoff scandal, 07/08 crisis, etc... taught us, people in the financial industry make up numbers, as they've done here.  The IEEE 754-2008 standard includes 3 decimal based floating point standards to give financial software easy to use decimal based rounding and exact representation of 0.1 .  All 3 sizes use a scheme that has sign, exponent, and significant information, but has different ranges and different representations in bits.