# Why big decimal is appending more decimal values

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Very basis question, i am trying to initialize a Big Decimal with value of 1.1, when i print it the output is not exactly 1.1

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(1.1);
System.out.println(bd1);
```

The output is

> 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

it works when if I use "1.1" (as string), or if i try to print bd1.doubleValue()

Can someone please explain this behavior, and what are those additional decimal digits auto generated.

Comment: Very important: always check the Javadoc first. The Javadoc for `BigDecimal(double)` answers your question exactly. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-

Answer (score 1):

It's because the number you're initializing it with - `1.1` - is a float! And as a float it can't represent `0.1` exactly - when represented as a binary number `0.1` has an infinitely repeating tail.  Look up how floats are represented and that'll be a canonical example.

Initialize some other way, e.g., with `11` then divide by `10` - you'll get what you want.

Here is [one stack overflow answer among many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448855/751579) that explains this property of floats.

Comment: `1.1` is a `double`, not a `float` (that would be `1.1f`)