# How can I justify that f64::from_bits(0x3fe9000000000000 u64 ) == 0.781250 f64

Tags: floating-point, hex, double, precision, fixed

I have slightly modified the original message with a second question :

I have been advised by a C++ expert to ckeck that out : 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

to understand better the representation of `double`, `memcpy`, and `bit_cast (C++20)` .

Here more specifically, I try to understand why we have that result from the code :

```
    constexpr std::uint64_t u64v2 = 0x3fe9000000000000ull;
    constexpr auto f64v2 = std::bit_cast<double>(u64v2);
```

`"f64::from_bits(0x3fe9000000000000u64) == 0.781250f64"`

Prior to it, I spent time to study the example which is provided in the example of fast inverse square root.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#CITEREFGoldberg1991

I did the calculus manually, and it turns out that I finally realised what happens in this specific case with an exponent of 8 bits and a mantissa of 23 bits.

But in the example I mentioned above as an application of `bit_cast`, it seems according to my research that the exponent is 11 bits, the mantissa 52 bits (with double precision) : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

When I did the calculs by hand, I found

```
x = (1+Mx/L)*2^(Ex-B)
```

with

```
 L=2^52 and Ex = 2*(2^9- 1) with the notations of
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#CITEREFGoldberg1991

And I don't find the result of `0.781250 as it is announced.
Maybe the exponent and mantissa I choosed was not correct.
I don't know, but I really would like to understand what happens.

Thanks in advance for your explanations to help to be to find `0.781250`

**2nd question** : please can you check the question i have asked below as reply to the comment because even I have a challenge with the first example. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `3fe9000000000000`, the first bit (zero) is the sign bit, so we can ignore that (it's positive).

The next 11 bits are `011.1111.1110` (`3fe`), which is `1022` but that is adjusted down by `1023` to handle negative exponents. It is therefore `-1`, which gives you the multiplier of `2-1`, or `0.5`.

The mantissa bits are `1001000..0` (the `9000..0` of your hex number). Those first four bits equate to the values `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.0125` and `0.0625` (halving each time). Since only the first and fourth bit are set, you get `0.5 + 0.0625 = 0.5625`.

Adding the implicit `1` to that number, as mandated by IEEE754, you get a base value of `1.5625`. When that's multiplied by the multiplier calculated earlier, you get:

```
1.5625 x 0.5 = 0.78125
```

So *that's* how you get your value.

---

Further detail can be found on the [IEEE754-1985 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), and you can experiment with [Harald Schmidt's excellent online converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), a tool so damn useful I built my own copy of it to handle double precision as well (not on the web unfortunately, it was a Java app for the desktop). It really *did* help me a lot in understanding.

You might also want to look at [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a14860%20ieee754) I've given on IEEE754, including, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855) in particular.

---

Regarding the bit pattern you brought up in a comment, `0x4172f58bc0000000` (which you state *should* be `19880124` but calculate something else), this is how you convert it:

```
4---> 1--> 7-->   2--> f--> 5--> 8--> b--> c--> (<- hex digits)
s eee eeee eeee   mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm
0 100 0001 0111   0010 1111 0101 1000 1011 1100 (<- then all zeroes)
  v      v  vvv     |  ||||  | | |    | || ||            1/n
  1      1  421     |  ||||  | | |    | || |+-------- 4,194,304
  0      6          |  ||||  | | |    | || +--------- 2,097,152
  2                 |  ||||  | | |    | |+----------- 1,048,576
  4                 |  ||||  | | |    | +------------   524,288
                    |  ||||  | | |    +--------------   131,072
                    |  ||||  | | +-------------------     8,192
                    |  ||||  | +---------------------     4,096
                    |  ||||  +-----------------------     1,024
                    |  |||+--------------------------       256
                    |  ||+---------------------------       128
                    |  |+----------------------------        64
                    |  +-----------------------------        32
                    +--------------------------------         8
```

The sign is positive.

The exponent is `1,024 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 1,047 - 1,023 bias = 24`, so the multiplier is `224` or `16,777,216`.

The mantissa bits sum, with each bit adding `1/2n` as `n` starts at `1` and increases to the right:

`1/4,194,304`,
`1/2,078,152`,
`1/1,048,576`,
`1/524,288`,
`1/131,072`,
`1/8,192`,
`1/4,096`,
`1/256`,
`1/128`,
`1/64`,
`1/32`, and
`1/8`.

When you add all these up along with the implicit `1`, you get `1.1849477291107177734375`.

Then, the product of that and the previously calculated multiplier of `16,777,216` is the value you want, `19,880,124‬`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I understood better now. I had an error in calculating the L , the bias exponent. I took `2^11 - 1`, whereas , I shoud take `2^10 - 1`.

Comment: Good evening, I continued to read the page and to verify. It seems there is a mistake ? because this is written (for the first example) : 19880124.000000f64.to_bits() == 0x4172f58bc0000000u64 I verified manually , and it seems that it is false. This would be : 12f58bc0000000. Can you confirm what I say or correct me and explain (if i was wrong)? thanks

Comment: @Dev, I added a bit to the end showing how to do that particular bit pattern. Hope that helps.

Comment: My question is inverse : how from `19,880,124`  can we obtain 0x4172f58bc0000000u64   ?   Thank you   .Yes, the other sense is easy for me, as the first example I have sent

Comment: @Dev, there are quite a few good vids on YouTube if you search for `ieee754 how to turn decimal number into bit pattern`. It's basically converting to a binary fraction then normalising to binary scientific notation.

Comment: I tried manually the opposite sense, and I think it is much longer, I could find the exponent manually : 417

Comment: It remains the mantissa : 0.18494772911 to calculate. It would be a bit long. I think I have understood the principle. This video was useful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBHUGy1xteg

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your number lays out in IEEE-745 DP format:

```
                  6    5          4         3         2         1         0
                  3 21098765432 1098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
                  S ----E11---- ------------------------F52-------------------------
          Binary: 0 01111111110 1001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             Hex: 3FE9 0000 0000 0000
       Precision: DP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -1 (Stored: 1022, Bias: 1023)
       Hex-float: +0x1.9p-1
           Value: +0.78125 (NORMAL)
```