# What are two numbers of 16 decimal digits precision that map to the same double-precision float?

Tags: floating-point, binary, precision, floating-accuracy

It is said that any decimal number expressed with 15 digits of precision within the range covered by double-precision floats can be uniquely identified with a particular float. But, that if we include more digits of precision (i.e. 16), we may see that two or more decimal numbers correspond to the same float. See https://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/ for more details.

Could someone please provide me with an example of two number with 16 decimal digits precision that map to the same double-precision float?

Comment: Changed it again to make sure it's discussing *precision* because technically, `1000000000000000` is a 16-digit decimal number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try large 16 *decimal* digit integers of the form `9 xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  //unsigned long long x0 = 9000000000000000;
  unsigned long long x0 = 1uLL << 53; // 9,007,199,254,740,992
  unsigned long long x1 = 9999999999999999;
  unsigned long long same = 0;
  for (unsigned long long x = x0; x <= x1; x++) {
    double f0 = (double) x;
    double f1 = (double) (x + 1);
    if (f0 == f1) {
      if (same++ == 0) {
        printf("%llu (0x%llX) %llu (0x%llX) both value the value of %f\n", //
            x, x, x + 1, x + 1, f0);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Repeats = %llu\n", same);
}
```

We rapidly find

```
    9007199254740992 (0x20000000000000) 9007199254740993 (0x20000000000001) both value the value of 9007199254740992.000000
    Repeats = 1
```

`9007199254740993 (0x20000000000001)`  is a 54-binary digit value.  Common [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can only *exactly* encode up to 53-significant binary digit values.

---

Another way to look at it [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Given common `double` encoding of 52 binary digits per each power-of-2.  Between [0.5 ... 1.0), there are 2<sup>52</sup> or
4,503,599,627,370,496 different `double` values.  Yet in that range there are 5,000,000,000,000,000 different 16 digit *decimal* values of the form `0.add ddd ddd ddd ddd d` (`a` = [5...9], `d` = [0-9]), so there is not enough distinct `double` values to map uniquely to all the 16 decimal digit values of that range.  Some decimal values will map to the same `double`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  //                  1234567890123456
  long long x1 =      9999999999999999; // 0x23 86F2 6FC0 FFFF
  char prior[40] = "0.9999999999999999";
  for (long long x = x1; --x > 0; ) {
    char buf[40];
    sprintf(buf, "0.%16lld", x);
    double value = atof(buf);
    if (value == atof(prior)) {
      printf("%s %s both have value %.20g\n", prior, buf, value);
      break;
    }
    strcpy(prior, buf);
  }
  printf("Done\n");
}

0.9999999999999995 0.9999999999999994 both have value 0.99999999999999944489
Done
```

Comment: The brute force search is nice. The pigeon hole principle is a nice obvious proof that there MUST be two 16 digit precision decimal numbers that map to the same float.

Answer (score 3):

In double precision, you have about 52 binary digits of precision (this translates to the roughly 15 decimal digits), that can scale up and down the exponent "curve"<sup>(1)</sup>. This means that a number made up of powers of two will only be differentiable if all of those powers of two are within that distance from each other (on the curve).

So, `250` and `250 + 2-10` will almost certainly become the same number, because the distance between the two terms of that second number differ by 60 on the curve.

Running the following C code confirms this:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double d1 = pow(2, 50);
    double d2 = d1 + pow(2, -10);

    if (d1 == d2) puts("Same");
    return 0;
}
```

---

In terms of two numbers with 16 decimal digits of precision, that's also doable, as `252` is about `4.5 x 1015`. That doesn't *quite* reach `1016` so what you need to look for is numbers with mostly zeros but a significant one-bit at the top and bottom of the mantissa.

This can be achieved (in one way) with a `9` at the left, and a `1` at the right, so `9.000000000000001` and `9.000000000000002`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double d1 = 9.000000000000001;
    double d1 = 9.000000000000002;

    if (d1 == d2) puts("Same");
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> By curve here, I mean logarithmic scale, where the distance between `210` and `213` is `3`.

The way a number is constructed is that the *mantissa* (or *fraction*) bits create a base number formed by consecutive powers of two. So the bits `101` could create `22 + 20`, or `5` (there's actually an implicit `1` bit at the start in IEEE-754, but we'll ignore that for simplicity).

The *exponent* bits are then used to scale, or multiply by another power of two, so you could for example, multiply that `5` by `24 = 16` to get `80`, or `2-10 = 1/1024` to get `0.0048828125`.

And, for completeness, the single sign bit then decides whether it's a positive or negative value. Both that, and the various bit patterns that give you special numbers like `NaN` and the infinities, are also ignored here because they're not really relevant to the question.

So, in order for a number to be differentiable from another, the most significant and least significant bits must fit within the limited-size mantissa.

See [my earlier answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855) for more detail on how this all works.

Comment: I see that 2^50 = 1125899906842624 is a 16 digit integer, but it looks like 2^50 + 2^-10 = 1125899906842624.0009765625 which is a 26 digit decimal. The question is seeking two 16 digit decimal numbers that map to the same float, not just any two decimal numbers that map to the same float.

Comment: @Jagerber48: yes, I hadn't read your question closely enough. I've left in the explanation as to how the IEEE-754 representation works because it's important to understanding. I've also added the way in which you can *find* two doubles with 16 decimal digits precision which can't be differentiated, and provided an example.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this question I found an answer in the comments on the linked article.
The 16 digit decimals

8.000 000 000 000 001

and

8.000 000 000 000 002

map to the same float.

In Python, I see

```
>>> float(8.000000000000001) == float(8.000000000000002)
True
```

Comment: `nextafter` might be useful know about (in Python's `math` module).  also using the `decimal` module to see the full decimal expansion can help to see the actual value represented by a given float